# How can I get logcat logs during onTouchEvent?

Tags: android

I have found I cannot get logcat logs during onTouchEvent. On the other hand, I could do it at least six months ago. 
This is what I've done and I got the result logs.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent motionEvent) {

    switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            Log.d("", "ACTION_DOWN");
            Log.d("", "EventLocation X:" + motionEvent.getX() + ",Y:" + motionEvent.getY());
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            Log.d("", "ACTION_UP");
            long eventDuration2 = motionEvent.getEventTime() - motionEvent.getDownTime();
            Log.d("", "eventDuration2: " +eventDuration2+" msec");
            Log.d("", "Pressure: " + motionEvent.getPressure());

            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            Log.d("", "ACTION_MOVE");
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            Log.d("", "ACTION_CANCEL");
            break;
    }

    return false;
}

}
```

Then, I got logs as follows:

```
14:58:25.693  ....testtouchevent D/ ACTION_DOWN
14:58:25.693  ....testtouchevent D/ EventLocation X:196.18164,Y:464.0
14:58:25.723  ....testtouchevent D/ ACTION_MOVE
14:58:25.733  ....testtouchevent D/ ACTION_MOVE
14:58:25.753  ....testtouchevent D/ ACTION_MOVE
14:58:25.813  ....testtouchevent D/ ACTION_UP
14:58:25.813  ....testtouchevent D/ eventDuration2: 118 msec
14:58:25.813  ....testtouchevent D/ Pressure: 0.38823533
```

I think  Android 6.0 or Android Studio1.4  stopped that. 
Is it one of the changes of Android 6.0?

In fact, it is possible to set TextView message in stead of Log.d, but that way is not so good.
Anyhow I want to know the reason.

ScreenShot:
[When I add a Log.d in the onCreate(), a log comes up.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIfeX.png)

Comment: Have you set log level on verbose + no filters?

Comment: Plz screenshot of you android studio

Comment: @tiny I added a screenshot. When I set a Log in the onCreate(), I got the log but no logs from onTouchEvent.

Comment: @dabo Thanks! I could get logs with setting [No Filters]. I believed logs should come from my application. But, in this case, logs of onTouchEvent are issued from "system_process."

Answer (score 0):

Android SDK provides a deafult class LogView http://developer.android.com/samples/BasicContactables/src/com.example.android.common.logger/LogView.html which you can use as a view in your application while development.

Alternatively take look at

https://github.com/jgilfelt/GhostLog

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jtb.alogcat

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nolanlawson.logcat

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BeamLargeFiles/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/common/logger/LogView.java

Comment: GostLog may be useful for a GPS field test. Thanks.